# When i use antd with tailwindcss i get an error useContext but i did'nt use useContext

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, antd

```
import { UserOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
const Navbar = () => {


return(
    <div className=" w-screen h-10 bg-lime-300 flex fixed items-center justify-end">
      <div className="flex mr-8 ">
        <UserOutlined />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

When i use Antd the program give an error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYmDL.jpg)

Comment: it is not a matter of antd or tailwind, as you can see the error says that you have a null usecontext and you are trying to read it. therefore, the problem is your usecontext.

Comment: I did'nt use useContext in this project

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)